# Please can we have different tags for different types of Ubuntu

Tags: support, tags

I do not have enough rep to create tags, but I think that there is a need now for tags to differentiate between types of Ubuntu. These are the one which are most prevalent on the RPi, the ones which I think need tags:

[ubunut-mate](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubunut-mate)

[ubuntu-snappy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-snappy)

[ubuntu-server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-server)

These are all very different, and it would be great to have an appropriate tag for each.

Would it be possible for someone to create these tags?

Thank you

Comment: Tags can only be added to existing questions (there's no way of creating a tag without questions attached to it). Do you have any examples of where these tags are necessary?

Comment: @Aurora0001: I don't have any specific questions, I was mostly thinking of new questions.  For example, I have experience with Ubuntu MATE, but not other types of Ubuntu. If questions were tagged [ubuntu-mate] I would be able to find and answer relevant questions more easily.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer (yet), just part of a discussion. The same idea probably applies to Raspbian as the major OS on the Pi. Unfortunately this is how questions are tagged in reality.

```
raspbian × 4934
raspbian-lite × 24
raspbian-stretch × 23
raspbian-jessie × 3
```

If implementing different tags for different types of Ubuntu key would be to transport that to the user base and have new (and preferably a large part of the old) questions properly tagged.

One other thing: I wonder how it would work out for those users that either follow or search for the generic tag if the specific sub-tags exist. We certainly would not want questions to be tagged both [ubuntu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) and [ubuntu-whatnot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-whatnot). It must be a common issue on SO maybe we check first.

Comment: I would gladly embark on a crusade to re-tag questions! :|)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the problems I have with this:

- Tags are primarily to help people find information, and having umpteen forms of Ubuntu does not help with this here.
- 90% of questions involving Ubuntu will apply equally well to any version thereof, but given the chance, 90% of people asking questions involving Ubuntu will want to use a more specific tag indicating the version they use.  Probably 75%+ of questions people *think* are specific to Ubuntu aren't, but this is less of an issue since then the tag is just spurious, but variant tags  would be used to replace a more general one (unless they use both, which is a bit clutter).
- The major difference between Ubuntu server and Mate is going to be the presence of a default GUI.  Any question which relates to this difference does not belong here, it belongs on Ask Ubuntu.

That said, I can see a possible value in a [ubuntu-snappy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-snappy) tag -- but we already have that, [snappy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/snappy).  I've added the former as a suggested synonym for this.