# Synonymise [stretch] and [raspbian-stretch] (and friends)

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation, tag-synonyms

I've noticed a couple of synonyms regarding Raspbian versions that would benefit from being synonyms:

- [jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jessie) (441 questions) and [raspbian-jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-jessie) (4 questions)
- [stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stretch) (76 questions) and [raspbian-stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-stretch) (40 questions)

There is also a [wheezy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheezy) tag but no [raspbian-wheezy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-wheezy). As for which tags should be the master tag and which the synonym: I personally think [raspbian-*] would work better, and would make it slightly easier [if [raspbian] was ever to be split into version tags](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1026/58316).  However, it appears that the other tags (just the version names alone) are more popular with question askers.

We also have the semi-redundant tags [raspbian-lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-lite) and [jessie-lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jessie-lite), although it's not clear whether they should be synonymsied as [raspbian-lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-lite) could also have questions about Stretch Lite.

**Can (and indeed should) these tags be synonyms?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made the following merges:

[wheezy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheezy) -> [raspbian-wheezy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-wheezy)

[jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jessie) -> [raspbian-jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-jessie)

[stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stretch) -> [raspbian-stretch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-stretch)

All with synonyms so they don't reappear.

As for the lite forms, I suppose they can follow the same pattern -- since there is still a plain [raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian) there might as well be a [raspbian-lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspbian-lite), then a [jessie-lite](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jessie-lite), etc.

Realistically, most questions would either be "lite" specific or else specific simply to wheezy/jessie/stretch.  Being specific but not too specific is of course better in general ;) but the ideal and the real often diverge.

I don't pay enough attention to tags when looking at a question with the ideal in mind, this is something I will try to do more.  If anyone else notes a question with a too specific tag, please consider swapping it for the more general.

However, when in doubt I think the more specific should apply (which justifies the 'foo-lite', 'bar-lite' tags).

Comment: Indeed, and in an ideal world, [tag:raspbian] would be replaced with the specific version tags (looks like it even has "DO NOT USE" in the description), but it continues to be used anyway. The disruption of retagging 5,000 questions almost certainly outweighs the benefits, although I do wish something could be done about it to avoid so many questions being dumped under the same tag.